# How to align a column using the vi editor?

Tags: vi

I have a column in numbers like below

```
-0.01343
0.002
-1.1234
```

I want to align the column in vi editor like below

```
-0.01343
 0.002
-1.1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to insert a space before each line not starting with a minus:

The appropriate command is is `:%s/^\([^-]\)/ \1/`

This breaks down as:

`:` - start command

`%s` - regex on all lines

`/^\([^-]\)` - matching the start of the line, followed by any character other than `-`, which we will call group 1

`/ \1` - replace with a space followed by whatever was in group 1

`/` - end regex, perform no more than once on each line

Other options:

If you select the intended lines in a visual block, typing `:` will start the command with `'<,'>`. Then move onto the regex starting with `s` (no `%`) and it will apply only to the selected lines.

If you end it with a `/c` it will ask for confirmation on each replacement. If you end it with `/g` it will work multiple times per line if applicable. `/gc` is valid.

If you'd wanted the decimal points to be aligned, rather than the first digits, that's more complex and probably cannot be done with a simple command in vi or vim.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
:%s/-.*\zs\|^/
```

`-.*` match every line that contains - sign

`\zs` inverse the selection

`\|` match every other lines

`/`   replace with space